# Unrecognized font family ionicons

Tags: react-native, native-base

I  followed the setup instructions in the [NativeBase Docs](http://nativebase.io/documentation) and ran `rnpm link`. I am getting this error: 
[Unrecognized font family ionicons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjfZB.png)

also checked by Xcode, the fonts are already in the build phase.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 84):

For RN 0.60+ **don't** use `react-native link ...`! (see [Autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md))

Instead add this in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

and run `pod update` (or `pod install`).

Furthermore add this in your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

(took from https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-cocoapods)

Works fine in my project with:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.1",
"native-base": "2.13.8" (react-native-vector-icons@6.6.0),
```

Comment: I have tried every other solution and this is the only one that worked for react-native 0.61.5   

Comment: Now It works properly on React Native 0.63.2
Thanks Man!

Comment: This solved my problem after I have followed several answers and tutorials here on the internet, but although the application compile, all icons appear with a "?" In place of the image. You could tell me why this happens, if needed, I post a question with more detail.
thankful @Eddy.

Answer (score 20):

Expanding on the exisiting answer and using the solution found on [this github issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/72), do the following;

1. Close the running packager
2. Run `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`
3. Then run `react-native start --reset-cache`
4. Finally run `react-native run-ios` to restart the simulator

Comment: Also remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` before step 2

Comment: Closing the packager (running terminal) was my problem.

Answer (score 19):

Use the `Icon.loadFont()` method to load the fonts.

Example (Add your App.tsx):

```
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

AntDesign.loadFont().then();
Ionicons.loadFont().then();
Feather.loadFont().then();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for people coming here in 2021.

Comment: This does not work for me. It results in the error `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Font failed to load`

Comment: 2023 this solution works

Answer (score 6):

if you are using 0.60 and above then you need to do the following step :-

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
 <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
 <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
 <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
 <string>Feather.ttf</string>
 <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
 <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
 <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
 <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
 <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
 <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
<string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Octicons.ttf</string>
<string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

and after this run below command:-

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

After clean and build. Run the ios app. This solution work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you start your packager and then link packages through `rnpm link`.

This requires you to restart your packager and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Editing PodFile and adding pod `RNVectorIcons` not necessary because **auto-linking** will work fine after adding **react-native-vector-icons**

adding to PodFile will cause a warning after the next run with `react-native run-ios`:

```
Warning: following modules are linked manually: - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons"
```

Just add this line of codes to your **info.plist** that exist on ios/yourPorjectName/

find **UIAppFonts** and add codes inside :

```
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
```

worked with:

"react-native": "0.63.3",

"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"

Answer (score 1):

native-base has **'react-native-vector-icons'** as dependency but if you are using react-native <=0.59.10 then you have link.

Just simple command :

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my mac.solution :

- Close the terminal window and simulator.
- On the same folder which your project is situated *write following*..
  React-native link react-native-vector-icons
- then start the project by., 
  React-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

If your iOS project is using CocoaPods (contains Podfile) and linked library has podspec file, then react-native link will link the library using Podfile.

Add the comment below to the bottom of your podfile.

```
# Add new pods below this line
```

Then run "react-native link [package_name]"

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me :

- Put `Ionicons.loadFont()`
- Close and reopen your application

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31490067)