# Unrecognised font family ‘Ionicons’ error - Native Base

Tags: ios, react-native, icons, native-base

I am trying to use native base icons in my app but every time i am getting **Unrecognized font family ‘Ionicons’ error**. I searched it on google and tried everything. like 
     rm -rf node_modules && npm install
     react-native link react-native-vector-icons
     react-native start --reset-cache

can anybody tell me some basic setups like where should I create my resource folder and all for this fix?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you using create-react-native-app? I just added native-base to my crna project and saw this error.

Comment: yes. I fixed this issue by adding the file in my BuildPhase > copy bundle resource section

Comment: For React Native **0.60+** see my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713240/unrecognized-font-family-ionicons/58133303#58133303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to create folder call "Resources" in your Xcode project and place Ionicons.ttf file inside that folder.
Try setup iOS Manually here (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

- Browse to node_modules/react-native-vector-icons and drag the folder
  Fonts (or just the ones you want) to your project in Xcode. Make sure
  your app is checked under "Add to targets" and that "Create groups"
  is checked if you add the whole folder.
- Edit Info.plist and add a    property called Fonts provided by
  application.[image]

Comment: Thanks, This helped me !

Comment: @RajuyourPepe,  you can open your react native iOS project from xcode just opening  .xcodeproj file from your project path (yourProjectFolder>>ios>>yourProject.xcodeproj)

Comment: In my case dragging the Fonts folder wasn't needed. Just referenced `Ionicons.tff` and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

for anyone facing similar issue while using the following combination

> "native-base": "^2.8.1",
>       "react": "16.6.1",
>       "react-native": "0.57.7",
>       "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.10",
>       "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
>       "react-navigation": "^3.0.8",

first clean the node_modules folder, then reinstall and also link

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
react-native link
```

then from **xcode clean and then build** for the ios project and run it in the simulator from xcode itself.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue.
Following steps helped me out:

1. Install `react-native-vector-icons` npm
2. Install pod

And you are good to go.